# Correctly save .mp4 file in C# from blob

Tags: c#, file, mp4

I want to save a .mp4 file from an array of bytes. This bytes came trought a websocket, and represent user's webcam and microphone recording when using `getUserMedia()` in supported browsers like Chrome or Firefox. When i processed everything, and I only need to join the multiple parts of the video and save it, I have this code:

```
foreach (TransFile tf in ltf.Value.OrderBy(m=>m.sequence)){
     using (BinaryWriter writer = 
               new BinaryWriter(File.Open("d:\\" + ltf.Key + ".mp4", FileMode.Append)))
               {
                    writer.Write(tf.bytes);
               }    
}
```

The file ends in my D drive, but there is a problem with the output video:

[image]

This happens when I try to open it using VLC...the only player that opened my video was BSPlayer. How can I save this file so any player can open it?

UPDATE: In order to fix codec error I converted the saved file using `ffmpeg` to be able to play this file in a player, locally or using an HTML5 player on a web page.

Comment: you cant just write bytes to a file and call it `.mp4` it has to be encoded in mp4 (you need a lib)

Comment: @EpicKip: That depends whether the bytes are already in the MP4 format or not, though. They're obviously not in ihavenokia's case...!

Comment: @Paul That's true!

Comment: I would wage a guess and say it's not already encoded, hence the error.

Comment: You could try https://www.bento4.com/. I would hazard a guess, though, that you're in for a world of pain!

Comment: This question isn't answerable.

Comment: I've edited my question, is it more clear now? I really want to fiz all issues in my questions so I get out of ban. Please help me, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there is no correct solution for your question. But I'll try to shed some light on it.

There is 2 things about an Audio and/or Video file you need to know. Packing and Encoding. You can read this [article](https://streaminglearningcenter.com/blogs/should-your-next-encoder-be-a-packager.html) about this topic.

MP4 is a Encoding, but a MP4 file can be packed in many different structures, this can be the problem with run you video in more simplified players.

Also, if your binary data isn't a MP4 file, you can save as MP4 but this won't make this video data to be a MP4 file. Maybe you are saving some other format with a name of .MP4 file.

Finally, if you need to guarantee save in MP4 you need to incorporate in your program an video converter to check the format and convert if it's needed.

Comment: Thank you, now I have some keywords to put in my google searches ;)